# statsmodel AR model answers wrong

Tags: python, numpy, statsmodels

I am trying to replicate the following R code in Python

```
set.seed(1)
x<-w<-rnorm(100)
for (t in 2:100) x[t] = 0.6 * x[t-1] + w[t]
x.ar = ar(x, method="mle")
x.ar$ar
[1] 0.5231187
```

In python I have the following code.

```
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import statsmodels.tsa.ar_model as ar_model
x = w = stats.norm.rvs(loc=0, scale=1, size=100)
for i in range(1,100):
    x[i] = 0.6* x[i-1] + w[i]


ar = ar_model.AR(x)
model_ar = ar.fit(method='mle')
print(model_ar.params)
[  9.26969930e-04   8.58915676e-01   2.74538400e+00  -1.49505968e+00
-3.47150385e+00   9.64130378e-02   2.68088493e+00   1.64061441e+00
-1.38189445e+00  -1.65265872e+00   6.33895141e-01   5.68494490e-01
-2.23487269e-01]
```

In python it seems to fit an order 13 model. How can I make it fit the simplest model?

Comment: When you do `ar.fit(method='mle')`, are you asking if you can set a `maxlag`?  Ex: `ar.fit(maxlag=1, method='mle')`? I could be way off.

Comment: An answer is already given, so just a side comment. There are many reasons you can't just say "the AR answer is wrong" here. The data is not the same even though similarly generated, and methods used can be different - noise term is not insignificant. Moreover, if you'd generated more examples in R, you'd have seen that `ar` not always fits 1-order model.

Comment: A tag 'pandas' is irrelevant, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [docs](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR.fit.html#statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR.fit): for `statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR.fit()`, you either select an information criterion (parameter `ic`) to determine the number of lags:

> Criterion used for selecting the optimal lag length. aic - Akaike
>   Information Criterion bic - Bayes Information Criterion t-stat - Based
>   on last lag hqic - Hannan-Quinn Information Criterion If any of the
>   information criteria are selected, the lag length which results in the
>   lowest value is selected. If t-stat, the model starts with maxlag and
>   drops a lag until the highest lag has a t-stat that is significant at
>   the 95 % level.

or provide a `maxlag` value. If the latter is missing, `statsmodels` uses default `round(12*(nobs/100.)**(1/4.))` to determine the number of lags to use.

Comment: I changed my code to `model_ar = ar.fit(method='mle', maxlag=1, disp=1, maxiter=1000)`. Now the params are `[ 0.00326174,  0.9942802 ]`

Comment: Per default, the model includes `trend='c'`, which means there's a constant as well. If you don't want this, just add `trend='nc'`.